# Scala split list into multiple lists

Tags: scala, list

I need to split a List into multiple list based on sum of size of an element. So this is what I wrote in to achieve this.
I am sure there will be a better way to write same in Scala. Any help is appreciated.

here is my code...

```
case class cs(name: String, size: Int)
val cl: List[cs] = List(cs("abc1", 3), cs("abc2", 2), cs("abc3", 1), cs("abc4", 2), cs("abc5", 2), cs("abc6", 1), cs("abc7", 5))

def splitBy(l: List[cs], chunkSize: Int = 5): List[List[cs]] = {

  var s = 0
  var tcl: List[cs] = List[cs]()
  var mcl: List[List[cs]] = List[List[cs]]()

  l.foreach{ e => {
    s = s + e.size
    if (s > chunkSize) {
      mcl = tcl +: mcl
      s = e.size
      tcl = Nil
    }
    tcl = e +: tcl
    println("TSize: " + tcl.size + " Elem: " + e + "Sum: " + s)
  }
  }

  mcl

}

println(splitBy(cl,5))
```

Comment: Not found: value `cs`; Not found: type `cs`.

Comment: here is definition of ca -case class cs(name: String, size: Int)

Comment: case class cs(name: String, size: Int)

Comment: The final result does not contain `abc7` at all. Is this intended?

Comment: You should edit your question with the definition of the case class as well as an example of the expected output for a given input

Comment: Thank you Andery for pointing about ABC7. Yes it should be included as well.

Comment: I just want to point out, that sometimes, a simple `while` or `for` loop with `vars` may have more benefits than strictly a functional solution. I myself, tried to post an answer using a recursive function with accumulator and gave up after my solution became much worse readable than the solution like above.

Comment: @ygor I somehow have the impression that there is an asymmetry in the api. The operations `List[List[X]] => List[X]` have nice syntactic sugar, while the operations `List[X] => List[List[X]]` are somehow always a mess with @tailrec's and reversed accumulators...

Answer (score 1):

```
  @tailrec
  def splitBy(l: List[cs], chunkSize: Int, innerAcc: List[cs] = List.empty[cs], outerAcc: List[List[cs]] = List.empty[List[cs]]): List[List[cs]] = (l, innerAcc) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) => outerAcc
    case (Nil, x) => x :: outerAcc
    case (x :: xs, a) =>
      if (x.size > chunkSize) {
        // Assumed we are ignoring anything > chunkSize
        splitBy(xs, chunkSize, a, outerAcc)
      }
      // You may want to pass sum forwards for efficiency rather than recalculate every time... 
      else if(x.size + a.map(_.size).sum > chunkSize) {
        splitBy(xs, chunkSize, List(x), a :: outerAcc)
      }
      else {
        splitBy(xs, chunkSize, x :: a, outerAcc)
      }
  }
```

Output

```
List(List(cs(abc7,5)), List(cs(abc6,1)), List(cs(abc5,2), cs(abc4,2), cs(abc3,1)), List(cs(abc2,2), cs(abc1,3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `foldLeft`, followed by a `map`, if ordering does not matter, you could get rid of the `reverse`s:

```
case class cs(name: String, size: Int)
val cl: List[cs] = List(cs("abc1", 3), cs("abc2", 2), cs("abc3", 1), cs("abc4", 2), cs("abc5", 2), cs("abc6", 1), cs("abc7", 5))

def splitBy(l: List[cs], chunkSize: Int = 5): List[List[cs]] =
  l.foldLeft(List[(List[cs],Int)]()) {
    case (accum @ (_, size: Int) :: _, next: cs) if size + next.size > chunkSize =>
      (next :: Nil, next.size) :: accum
    case ((chunk, size: Int) :: rest, next: cs) =>
      (next :: chunk, size + next.size) :: rest
    case (Nil, next: cs) =>
      (next :: Nil, next.size) :: Nil
  }.map {
    case (chunk, size: Int) =>
      chunk.reverse
  }.reverse

splitBy(cl, 5) foreach println
```

Output:

```
List(cs(abc1,3), cs(abc2,2))
List(cs(abc3,1), cs(abc4,2), cs(abc5,2))
List(cs(abc6,1))
List(cs(abc7,5))
```

---

I originally misinterpreted the question to mean you want chunks of *at least* `chunkSize`. This was my old response, which I'll leave here for posterity, using a `scanLeft` followed by `collect`:

```
case class cs(name: String, size: Int)
val cl: List[cs] = List(cs("abc1", 3), cs("abc2", 2), cs("abc3", 1), cs("abc4", 2), cs("abc5", 2), cs("abc6", 1), cs("abc7", 5))

def splitBy(l: List[cs], chunkSize: Int = 5): List[List[cs]] =
  l.scanLeft(List[cs]() -> 0) {
    case ((_, size: Int), next: cs) if size >= chunkSize =>
      (next :: Nil, next.size)
    case ((chunk, size: Int), next: cs) =>
      (next :: chunk, size + next.size)
  }.collect {
    case (chunk, size: Int) if size >= chunkSize =>
      chunk.reverse
  }

splitBy(cl, 5) foreach println
```

Output:

```
List(cs(abc1,3), cs(abc2,2))
List(cs(abc3,1), cs(abc4,2), cs(abc5,2))
List(cs(abc6,1), cs(abc7,5))
```

Comment: I thought I responded to this, but somehow the comment is not showing. I misinterpreted the question to mean each group should have _at least_ `chunkSize` values. Updated the answer to reflect that no group should have more than `chunkSize` values (unless of course, the element was already larger than `chunkSize` to start).